Reappending threads after starting them
I was just following a tutorial on the usage of subinterpreters in python 3.12 .
In the tutorial there is the following code snippet:
def run_in_threads(total: int = 10):
    sub_interpreters = []
    list_thread = []
    for i in range(total):
        sub_interpreters.append(subinterpreters.create())
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(sub_interpreters[i],))
        list_thread.append(t)

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(total):
        list_thread[i].start()
        list_thread.append(list_thread[i])

    for t in list_thread:
        t.join()

    print(f"Test subinterpreter has total execution time {time.time() - start}")
    for i in range(total):
        subinterpreters.destroy(sub_interpreters[i])

My question is regarding this specific line from above:
list_thread.append(list_thread[i])

What purpose does it serve to re-append the thread after starting it? Wouldn't this warp the list and the following steps?
I've tried the usual steps debugging, chatgpt, etc. but as I am not 100% sure what the wanted outcome was supposed to be I don't really know what to belive..
Thanks for the answers ^_

The code part you quote -
    for i in range(total):
        list_thread[i].start()
        list_thread.append(list_thread[i])

Is indeed just some distraction by the author of the tutorial.  As you noted, it doesn't make sense - and the code in all work because the only effect of the extra reference to the thread in this list is that .join() is called twice on it. Since .join() is idempotent and has no effect when called on already joined threads, nothing (bad) happens)
If you are playing around with subinterpreters, I will suggest you to pip install extrainterpreters (disclaimer: I am the author):
it not only does the correct import of the hidden module in Python 3.12 and 3.13 (as is in the tutorial) - but offers a drop-in wrapper for threading.Thread: you can just set a target function in your code (either in the REPL or in a code file), and run it in other thread, on the other interpreter.
(but unfortunatelly, I didn't get communication primitives to work proper yet, so you won't get a proper Queue or Lock that works with them - but you can check the result of a function running in another interpreter. )

thanks a lot! your module looks quite interesting and should make my program quite a bit simpler..

I should be fiddling with it a bit more now Python 3.13 is on the hoirzon.  (even yesterday I pushed an update in order for it to work with python 3.13 RC1 - as they had changed the name of the provisional "interpreters"  module
